# DD4T: Add Target Groups TBB

Tags: dd4t

I am trying to add Target Groups information in my DD4T page, I am trying to use the AddTargetGroup TBB but with no results. I used it in two ways

1. Using AddTargetGroups only
2. Using AddTargetGroups and Generate Dynamic Page

Both combinations generates an empty `<conditions>` element that doesn't contain any Target Group information

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Could it be that the TBB is looking for a output containining <tcdl:ComponentPresentation /> tags in order to add conditions to them, and since it doesn't find them in DD4T's output, it does nothing?

Comment: The <conditions> element was empty because my target groups were Expression Target Groups, I added a new TBB to the DD4T templates called Add Expression Target Groups in order to solve that issue

Comment: Post this as an answer to your own Q if you've solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

The `<conditions>` element was empty because my target groups were Expression Target Groups. Expressions Target Groups don't have the Conditions property populated, I added a new TBB to the DD4T templates called Add Expression Target Groups in order to solve that issue